# setFirstResult/setMaxResults methods not working for Pagination

Tags: oracle, hibernate, pagination

I have a table say Employee and there are columns id, status , name (and few more columns). Id is unique for each record and status will have either of two value ("Active" or "Inactive"). 
When I am trying to sort on status column and using pagination(max no. of records to display in 1 page is 10) then from 2nd page new sets of records are not fetched. Please note 95% of records have "Active" status i.e. on sorting on status 1st to 8th page have status column value as "Active". Please let me know how to fix the issue.
I am using Hibernate and Oracle is my database.

Thanks
Abhishek.

Comment: Can you post your query?NOT hibernate

Comment: It's better to provide your current solution to see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Please find below query

Comment: String qyertStr = select id, first name, last name, dept, job level, status from Employee order by status ASC
Query query = entityMgrObj.createQuery(queryStr, entityClass); // entityclass if Employee class mapped to Employee table

Comment: I have not found any solution yet. Instead of solution I have workaround in mind that we can add one more column for sorting like id which is unique